# How to connect WiFi from CLI?

Tags: networking, raspberrypi

On Raspberry Pi (2 B) I have ubuntu. I don't know how to connect to wifi network with CLI. Do you know?

Comment: MATE or Snappy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
nmcli d wifi connect <WiFiSSID> password <WiFiPassword> iface wlan0
```

Comment: I think `iface wlan0` can be omitted.